# Save website to homescreen on iPhone vs. direct entrance - differences?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

When I enter http://pattern.dk/sun/ (web mobile app) it asks me to add it to homescreen of iPhone. Otherwise I only see "add to home screen" message and not actual application. Adding it to homescreen and running it from there makes it display application.

But I would like to open that application in Chrome. Setting "iPhone iOS5" user agent in Chrome makes it display the same "add to home screen" message and not application itself.

I'm wondering what are the differences between entering application added to iPhone's home screen and Safari entrance? Can I see that application in Chrome in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The distinction can be made using JavaScript:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    // Web app on the homescreen
} else {
    // Mobile Safari
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to display it in Chrome as an application?

Comment: @Paul As long as you can make Chrome pretend Mobile Safari and you manage to set `window.navigator.standalone` to `true`, it is.